# emacs on console "can not load file, package

Tags: terminal, emacs

In my .emacs file, I try to install el-get with this code:

```
(unless (require 'el-get nil 'noerror)
  (require 'package)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives
               '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
  (add-to-list 'package-archives
                      '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-initialize)
  (package-install 'el-get)
  (require 'el-get))
(add-to-list 'el-get-recipe-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get-user/recipes")
(el-get 'sync)
```

and get this in *Messages*:

```
Loading /Users/koxmoz/.emacs...
if: Cannot open load file: package
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Where/how did you install `package`?

Comment: I don't install anything yet... on linux that code works without installing package. I think it comes with built-in.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `package` nor `el-get` are part of a standard OS X installation, they need to be installed manually.

But unless you are really keen on running `emacs` in terminal mode, I would recommend to install [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org) instead which provides a much better integration with OS X. Also, `package` is part of the standard installation.